# nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid parameter index 1

Tags: java

I get following Error, but I can not understand why:

> org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException:
>   PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [UPDATE da_tracking SET
>   ins_name= xyz, ins_dev_scripted = False WHERE ins_ID = 12]; nested
>   exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid parameter index 1.

```
------------------------ dao class-----
public int save(DboBean record) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String sql = "UPDATE da_tracking"
                    + " SET ins_name= " + record.getDboDevName()+ "," 
                    + " ins_dev_scripted = " + record.getDevScripted()
                    + " WHERE ins_ID = " + record.getDboId();
        Object[] params = new Object[] {record.getDboDevName(), record.getDevScripted()};
        int[] types = new int[]{Types.VARCHAR, Types.BIT};
        return jdbcTemplate.update(sql, params, types);
    }
----------------------------Junit-----
bean.setDboDevName("xyz");
bean.setDboId(12);
int rowsAffected =  objDao.save(bean);

    System.out.println("Object is updated [" + bean.getDboId() + ", " + bean.getDboDevName() + 
            ", " + bean.getDevScripted() + "]");
```

Do you know why?? 
My delete & read Methods work.

Answer (score 4):

The error you are seeing is because you are passing variables in to the `params` and `types` arrays, but you haven't put placeholders for those bind variables in your queries:

```
String sql = "UPDATE da_tracking"
            + " SET ins_name= ?," 
            + " ins_dev_scripted = ?"
            + " WHERE ins_ID = ?"
Object[] params = new Object[] {record.getDboDevName(), record.getDevScripted(), record.getDboId()};
int[] types = new int[]{Types.VARCHAR, Types.BIT, Types.INTEGER};
return jdbcTemplate.update(sql, params, types);
```

Internally, Spring is doing something like this:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("...your sql...");
stmt.setString(1, dboDevName); // this will fail, since there is no bind variable
                               // with index 1
...
```

You should NEVER build SQL queries by concatenating external data. In the best case, it will result in queries that will randomly fail if someone puts a strange quote or escape character in the data, and in the worst case, a major security hole which will compromise your system.

Answer (score 1):

```
public int save(DboBean record) {

        String sql = "UPDATE da_tracking"
                    + " SET ins_name= ?"+"," 
                    + " ins_dev_scripted = ?" 
                    + " WHERE ins_ID = ?";
        Object[] params = new Object[] {record.getDboDevName(), record.getDevScripted(), record.getDboId()};
        int[] types = new int[]{Types.VARCHAR, Types.BIT, Types.INTEGER}; // Change 3rd parameter type here
        return jdbcTemplate.update(sql, params, types);
    }

----------------------------Junit-----
bean.setDboDevName("xyz");
bean.setDboId(12);
int rowsAffected =  objDao.save(bean);

    System.out.println("Object is updated [" + bean.getDboId() + ", " + bean.getDboDevName() + 
            ", " + bean.getDevScripted() + "]");
```

Does this work?

Comment: You are correct that bind variables (paramaterized queries) should be used, but that's not the source of this error. You are right that the variable (probably only `ins_name`) needs to be quoted, but the SQL parser hasn't gotten that far into parsing the query yet.